# Alternative Proof of "Suppose R and S are transitive relations Prove that if $S\circ R \subseteq R\circ S$ then $R\circ S$ is transitive"

Tags: logic, relations

This question has already been solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394571/suppose-r-and-s-are-transitive-relations-prove-that-if-s-circ-r-subseteq).
But I wonder whether there is an easier prove if one uses that R is transitive if $R\circ R \subseteq R$.
I am not sure whether this can be used but this is what I tried:
$R\circ S$ is transitive if $$(R\circ S) \circ (R \circ S) \subseteq R\circ S$$
Since relations are associative we write:
$$(R\circ S) \circ (R \circ S) \subseteq R\circ (S \circ R) \circ S$$
Now comes the step I am not sure about since $S\circ R \subseteq R\circ S$:
$$R\circ (S \circ R) \circ S\subseteq R\circ (R \circ S)\circ S$$

Now I can use associativity again and get:
$$R\circ (R \circ S)\circ S\subseteq(R\circ R) \circ (S \circ S)$$
But since $R$ and $S$ are transitive
$R\circ R \subseteq R$ and $S\circ S \subseteq S$
$$(R\circ R) \circ (S \circ S)\subseteq R\circ S$$
as required.
Is this proof correct?

Comment: "Since relations are associative one can change this to:"  this is a very confusing sentence fragment, and makes no sense in the context of your proof.  I almost thought you were trying to transform the inclusion $$(R\circ S) \circ (R \circ S) \subseteq R\circ S$$ into some equivalent form.  It seems like here you you meant to say something like "Since relations are associative one can write:".  Otherwise this looks correct.

Comment: @MW yes you're right. I am changing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the proof is correct.
The only doubt I had was when I used $$S\circ R \subseteq R\circ S$$.
It is sufficient here to prove that if $A,B,C$ are relations then
$$A\circ B \circ C \subseteq A\circ B' \circ C$$ if $$B\subseteq B'$$
For this purpose suppose $(x,z)\in A\circ B \circ C$
Then from the definition of composition:
$$\exists y,w:(x,w)\in C \land(w,y)\in B\land(y,z)\in A$$
Since $B\subseteq B'$
$$(w,y)\in B'$$
And therefore we have
Then from the definition of composition:
$$\exists y,w:(x,w)\in C \land(w,y)\in B'\land(y,z)\in A$$
which means that $$(x,z)\in A\circ B' \circ C$$